# TypeError: mean() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: python, pytorch

I have recently upgraded the PyTorch version from 1.4 to 1.8. Now the mean function isn't working.

```
class loss_e(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, patch_size, mean_val):
    super(L_exp, self).__init__()
    # print(1)
    self.pool = nn.AvgPool2d(patch_size)
    self.mean_val = mean_val

def forward(self, x):
    # b, c, h, w = x.shape
    print(x)
    x = torch.mean(x, 1, True) # I got the error in this line 
    mean = self.pool(x)

    d = torch.mean(torch.pow(mean - torch.FloatTensor([self.mean_val]).cuda(), 2))
    return d
```

Here's the error I got.

```
File "/home/nemo/Desktop/AICE/Myloss.py", line 86, in forward
    x = torch.mean(x, 1, True)
TypeError: mean() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple, int, bool), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, *, torch.dtype dtype)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!tuple!, !int!, !bool!)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of names dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of ints dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
```

I have printed the x t make sure If it's a tensor or not.

```
tensor([[[[0.9581, 0.9584, 0.9575,  ..., 0.6204, 0.6114, 0.6179],
          [0.9608, 0.9616, 0.9611,  ..., 0.6609, 0.6543, 0.6619],
          [0.9606, 0.9612, 0.9606,  ..., 0.7257, 0.6903, 0.6772],
          ...,
```

Then I have printed x.shape and got this.

```
torch.Size([8, 3, 256, 256])
```

How this tensor is converted to a tuple?

Edit-

I have found that function invert causing that issue.
I have fed a inv_imag and img to the same model.

```
inv_image = torchvision.transforms.functional.invert(img)
```

There's no issue when I fed only the img.

Comment: what pytorch version are you using?

Comment: is it possible you call `loss_e` with more than one input tensor? Can you show the code that calls this loss function?

Comment: @Shai i'm using 1.8. I have made an edit to the question.